# CAS delegate authentication

Tags: authentication, cas

I'm using CAS server 4.x and I'm trying to delegate authentication using google. My idea is that a web application A redirects to CAS for login, there the user presses a "login using google" and then he gets redirected to log in using google.

To achieve that I created a client application (A).

I run A and it redirects me to the CAS login page, there I press the "login using google" link and it redirects me to login with google, there I login and consent.

On the CAS side the info from google is received ok and the TGT is created. However, the server fails to redirect to A cause it doesn't have the redirect info in the session:

ERROR [org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.web.OAuth20CallbackAuthorizeController] - oauth20_callbackUrl is missing from the session and can not be retrieved.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

This is how I configured everything:

First, I followed the steps mentioned here:
http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html

In the login view I added:
login using google

applicationContext:

```
<bean id="google" class="org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client">
    <property name="key" value="key" />
    <property name="secret" value="secret" />
</bean>

<bean id="clients" class="org.pac4j.core.client.Clients">
  <property name="callbackUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/cas/login" />
  <property name="clients">
    <list>
      <ref bean="google" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

cas servlet:

```
<bean id="clientAction" class="org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="centralAuthenticationService"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clients"/>
</bean>
```

deployerConfigContext:

```
<property name="authenticationMetaDataPopulators">
    <util:list>
       <bean class="org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.authentication.ClientAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
    </util:list>
</property>

 <bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"        
    class="org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.authentication.handler.support.ClientAuthenticationHandler"> 
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clients"/>
</bean>
```

Then I added an OAuth client in the deployerConfigContext:
registeredServicesList:

```
  <bean class="org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService">
    <property name="id" value="1" />
    <property name="name" value="serviceName" /> 
    <property name="description" value="Service Description" />

    <property name="serviceId" value="http://localhost:8080/A/" />
    <property name="clientId" value="123" />
    <property name="clientSecret" value="123" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get happens only if you enable OAuth **server** support, but what you want is to enable OAuth **client** support (based on `pac4j`) to be able to delegate the authentication to Google. You have the right link to the documentation, but you should check you followed every steps (there is no "OAuthRegisteredService").

Comment: I'm trying to do both, the CAS server acting as an OAuth server and also as an OAuth client to delegate. I'm going to re-check the documentation to enable server support.